# Androidtablet accept .NET Framework

Tags: android, .net

i have to create android tablet app use .net framework.

i don't know about these.

please explain me it is possilble to develop.

if possible means please explain the the  advantages and disadvantages of use these framework.

What is the fear factor of use .net framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mono for Android to develop using C# for the Android platform. The project is fairly mature at this time and produces binaries that are reasonably sized (it removes types in the framework that you don't use from the final binary)

Comment: The produced binaries may be quite small but the runtime environment is a really huge blob. Beside of that: Mono is and never was fully compatible with the original .NET platform from MS, so there are troubles preprogrammed.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use it? I don't know if there exist a stable .NET implementation for Android. If yes: it will be quite huge (containing all the functionalities that already existin in Android OS again). So your users would have to download/install dozens of MBytes of code to get functionality they already have. They will not like you for that ;-)

Comment: my client asking the question me like Will Android tablet accept .Net Framework? and what are the fear factors? ...i don't know about these.thats y i have post these question here